# How to get more than 20000 records from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am getting the users details from the active directory using the following code

```
DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=" + Domainname + ",dc=directoryname,dc=com", username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

DirectorySearcher DS = new DirectorySearcher(Entry);
List<string> lstPath = new List<string>();
DS.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=*)";
//DS.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=umbarglp)";
//DS.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=Adminumbarglp)";

SearchResultCollection ResultsCollection = DS.FindAll();
```

In this code I'm getting back only 20000 records not more than that. What I need to use get all the entries of AD.

Thanks in advance.
Eshwer

Comment: Why do you need more than 20k entries from AD? ... I'm amazed that AD stores this many records and that there aren't more efficient tools to work with it, so I'll assume you're writing such an amazing tool.

Comment: Try setting the PageSize on the DirectorySearcher instance.

Comment: @marc_s i have to get all records man that is client requirement that is not my personal issue.

Comment: @jcolebrand thr is more than 50000 records which i have to get...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the maximum returned records is never greater than the maximum configured on the server (see the [SizeLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.sizelimit.aspx) documentation). If it's possible to even further increase that amount, that would be the quickest solution, (although perhaps inadvisable in case of other programs also being able to get more records and causing overloads)

**edit**
Out of curiosity I wanted to test how this could be done by reading in chunks, this seems to work:

```
        DS.SizeLimit = 10; //set small for testing, change before production ;)            
        DS.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=*)";            
        var list = new List<SearchResult>();

        SearchResultCollection res;
        while ((res = DS.FindAll()).Count > 0)
        {
            list.AddRange(res.Cast<SearchResult>());       
            var last = list[list.Count - 1].GetDirectoryEntry().InvokeGet("sAMAccountName").ToString()
                + "0"; // <- small cheat to prevent doubles because the search does not support > , but does support >=
            DS.Filter = "(sAMAccountName>=" + last + ")";
        }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity I wanted to test how this could be done by reading in chunks, added a code snippet for that course.